# Random 10 letters .exe file at startup takes up 150MB of RAM then immediately kill itself

Tags: windows-7, memory, usb-flash-drive

A process named 'eepBn5hbZX.exe' takes over 180MB of RAM at startup (the computer is up for 55s) for a while before disappearing. It's pretty large (85.9MB) and located in the Desktop folder

[image]

This has been a problem since I stick an USB that is infected by a malware that sets the 'hidden' attributes to my files. I retype the .exe file address and it behaved exactly as it would at startup (does nothing but drain memory and kills itself a few seconds later).

How can I delete the file completely and prevent the same problem from recurring?

Comment: While not addressing your question, a general FYI that Windows 7 reaches EoL in ~2 months and will no longer receive security updates from Microsoft after that, unless you're on a business LTS agreement.

Comment: UPDATE: I found some new suspicious hidden files. My PC is personal, I don't have a credit account or any valuable information on it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqgq5.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWZW4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system has a virus or other malware.
These are classical symptoms.
And it seems your own virusscanner can't catch it.

Installing another anti-virus product is probably not gong to help, because anything you do on an already compromised system is unreliable. This also applies to manually trying to disable the malware. There are multiple components of it installed but you can only remove 1 at a time, so the others can simply re-active the one you just killed.

Best thing to do is to scan and clean the harddisk from a clean state:

1. Pull the harddisk out of the computer and hook it up to another (clean) computer as 2nd disk. Then scan the disk from the clean system. Use multiple anti-virus products if needed if the first doesn't find anything.
2. Alternatively: Some anti-virus products have a live-USB stick solution. You boot from the USB stick (in stead of the compromised harddisk) and scan the infected disk using the software on the USB stick. Obviously you will need to download and make the USB stick on another clean system.

See also the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) that RamHound just posted in the comments. I was going to link to that  same question but he was faster than me.

Comment: I don't have an antivirus software on my computer.

Comment: @jacker07 And now you know why that was a bad idea... But that doesn’t change the solution. The only way to be sure you have a clean system is to do the cleanup from a known good clean installation. Either another computer or another OS booted from clean media.